# Problema criação Aplicação Android - Java

Tags: java, android, app

Eu preciso de colocar uma série de questões, para um problema que me foi imposto, relativamente à criação de uma aplicação Android em Java.

Para descrever as circunstâncias, eu estou a criar uma app para servir a liga de futebol do meu colégio. Toda a parte "funcional" está criada. Esta app foi pensada para servir duas partes: os professores responsáveis pela administração da liga que apontam toda a informação e coordenam tudo, e os alunos que acedem a essa informação, nomeadamente a classificação, marcadores, resultados etc... 
Com a parte "funcional" refiro-me à aplicação para os professores, onde são criados os Maps com a informação de toda a liga. Essa parte trabalha bastante bem e tudo é armazenado em vários ficheiros de texto, no telemóvel do responsável.

De seguida acabei por criar uma simples cópia da aplicação dos professores, já mais apresentável, mas que apenas lesse os ficheiros de texto, sendo esta direcionada para os alunos.
A primeira questão é: Foi esta uma boa opção, ou poderia ter feito de outra forma a aplicação para os alunos?

Ora, agora o problema é o seguinte: Como é que poderei fazer para difundir a aplicação, mais concretamente os ficheiros de texto onde é armazenada a informação? Tendo em conta que terei de suportar 200/300 alunos, qual a forma mais fácil de os ficheiros de texto, criados a partir do telemóvel dos professores responsáveis, chegarem aos dispositivos dos alunos? 
Este é o meu grande problema, visto que eu nunca fiz nada deste género com estas dimensões.

Agradecia bastante se conseguisse algum conselho, alguma ideia.

Comment: Eu recomendaria o uso de um Backend-as-a-Service como o Firebase. Ele foi criado para exatamente esse tipo de caso de uso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma correta e elegante seria criar um webservice e colocá-lo na nuvem. E assim, a versão dos alunos e dos professores poderiam acessar às informações persistidas em um banco de dados. Exitem alguns serviços de nuvem gratuitos como Heroku e Openshift. Você poderia criar um web service soap ou web service rest, basicamente a diferença entre eles é que o web service soap utiliza somente xml para troca de informações, enquanto o web service rest utiliza xml, json e outros tipos.